# Draw an image from a file and set a center point, on wpf

Tags: wpf

I'm building a WPF application.
I have a path to an image and I can load it like this:

```
var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"path to image", UriKind.Relative));
```

I also have have a Center value:

```
var center = new Center(50, 50)
```

My question is: what is the best way to draw my image on a grid and specify it a center point. Something like this:

```
var myImage = new Something(img);
myImage.Center = center;
MyGrid.Children.Add(myImage);
```

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking.** What  are you really trying to do?

Comment: How do I draw that BitmaImage on my Grid and set it center coordinates?

Comment: With WPF Grid, you do not set coordinates. If you want something in the center, use `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` like the answer suggest. If you do need to work with coordinates for some reason you'll need `Canvas`.

Comment: @vesan I really needed to work with coordinates, I guess I'll look at Canvas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The xaml for what you're describing would look something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source={Binding SomeProperty) HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Off the top of my head, I think this would translate in C# terms to something like:

```
// Convert your BitmapImage to BitmapSource
BitmapSource source = Convert(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"path to image", UriKind.Relative)));

Grid grid = new Grid();
Image image = new Image
{
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    Source = source
};
grid.Children.Add(image);
```